# unable to display date on ionic 2 using ios/safari

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, safari, ionic2

Hi i am again facing the issue related to the date and time related in ios/safari. in chrome/android it is getting correctly but when comes to ios/Safari it is displaying the future date.

**below is the json response i am getting from server**

```
FromCurrentDate:"2018-01-17T06:00:00"
FromPreviousDate:"2018-01-16T06:00:00"

ToCurrentDate:"2018-01-17T20:14:08.067"
ToPreviousDate:"2018-01-16T20:14:08.067"
```

**and in android or Chrome it is displaying like below and data is accurate**

[image]

**But Where as the same in the safari it is displaying incorrectly**

[image]

it is displaying the future date in iOS and below is my template file/HTML File

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let singleTable of resultData;let ind=index">

        <p>Current{{singleTable[0].FromCurrentDate|date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} to {{singleTable[0].ToCurrentDate|date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}Previous :{{singleTable[0].FromPreviousDate|date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} to {{singleTable[0].ToPreviousDate|date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</p>
    </ion-card>
```

below are my timezone in device
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the issue but the timezone ,

Please check the timezone of ios/safari is same as android and chrome.

> If you want to display same time all over the glob then pass formatted
>   time from the server side , coz if time is formatted form the device
>   then it will convert it as per the device timezone.

Comment: Device time zone is set to IST and same for Mac also but the difference it is displaying it is related other timezone

Comment: Issue is very clear its client side rendering , and if you are converting date then it will convert based upon your device or browser.

Comment: Her in android/Chrome Browser working perfectly and now what i have to do

Comment: please check the i have updated the question along with screen shots & i have made the change like u told but no success

Comment: and it is taking Current Local Time in Darwin, Northern Territory, Australia

Comment: @TechieBoy, I think account linked with device is from Australia , Please check on other device , as this is not a issue , its showing time as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the safari does not understand the format "dd-MM-yyyy" like chrome does. You have to convert the response date to some other format like "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss" using Date() or Moment() and then use that value in your html. You can use the same pipe operator to format date as you want to display on screen.